# Plotting functions with many variables - organization

Tags: code-organization

Consider

```
f[a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, x_] = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^5;
g[a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, x_] = a0 + a1/x + a2/x^2 + a3/x^3 + a4/x^5;

Manipulate[
  Plot[{f[a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, x], g[a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, x]}, {x, -3, 3}]
  ,{a0, 0, 1}
  ,{a1, 0, 1}
  ,{a2, 0, 1}
  ,{a3, 0, 1}
  ,{a4, 0, 1}
]
```

If I have more functions like f and g which depend on the parameters `{a0,a1,a2,a3,a4}` or more parameters it becomes annoying to have to type them in every time, additionally the code becomes hard to read. It would be convenient if I could somehow bundle them into a list which could then be populated with the appropriate values from the manipulate and then passed into the plot function to be plotted.

For example I have tried things like the following:

```
f[P_, x_] := (a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^5)/.{a0->P[[1]],a1->P[[2]]/.a2->P[[3]]/.a3->P[[4]]/.a4->P[[5]]};
g[P_, x_] := (a0 + a1/x + a2/x^2 + a3/x^3 + a4/x^5)/.{a0->P[[1]],a1->P[[2]]/.a2->P[[3]]/.a3->P[[4]]/.a4->P[[5]]};

Manipulate[
  Plot[{f[P, x], g[P, x]}/.P->{a0,a1,a2,a3,a4}, {x, -3, 3}]
  ,{a0, 0, 1}
  ,{a1, 0, 1}
  ,{a2, 0, 1}
  ,{a3, 0, 1}
  ,{a4, 0, 1}
]
```

However I get issues here having to do with the order of evaluation of the replacements/plotting/manipulate operations which I don't understand how to correct.

I assume there is a not too difficult solution to this but I'm not very well versed in Mathematica syntax. I would appreciate any suggestions to help me 'bundle' these parameters into a more compact symbol.

Comment: Can you use anything like this? `xv={1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5};
av={a0,a1,a2,a,a4,a5};
Dot[av,xv]`

Comment: good suggestion. In my actual case the functions are more complicated functions of the parameters. I can post the form later if that will help. @eyeorble I’m looking through that answer. I’m not sure yet if it answers my question or not yet.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the answer linked in eyeorble's comment I was able to get the desired result with the following simple code.

```
f[a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, x_] = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^5;
g[a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, x_] = a0 + a1/x + a2/x^2 + a3/x^3 + a4/x^5;

funcs[a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, x_] = {f[a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, x], g[a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, x]}

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{funcs[a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, x]}], {x, -3, 3}]
, {a0, 0, 1}
, {a1, 0, 1}
, {a2, 0, 1}
, {a3, 0, 1}
, {a4, 0, 1}]
```

I would say the linked answer is a more automated version of this code, suitable for cases in which the number `n` of functions and variables is itself variable, whereas in my case this is fixed (or I at least don't feel the need for it to be programatically adjustable).
The Evaluate is necessary to get the different plot lines to stylize differently as desired.

Incidentally for the definition of `funcs` I can also write

```
funcs[P_, x_] = {f[P, x], g[P, x]}
```

Without changing anything else and getting the desired result. This is nice because it's a bit more compact I don't know why this works but I'm sure it has something to do with how functions and variable instances works.